# Some necessary condition for $\gcd(m,n) $ be a proper divisor of $\gcd(mk_2 +nk_1,mn) $

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, algebraic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $m,n,k_1,k_2 $ be natural numbers such that  $(k_1,m)=(k_2,n)=1 $.

**Statement 1**: $\gcd(m,n) $ is a proper divisor of $\gcd(mk_2 +nk_1,mn) $, for every $k_1,k_2$ having the above property.
**Statement 2**: The exponents of $2 $ in $m,n$ are same and greater than or equal to $ 1 $.

**Remarks**: the prime divisors of $\gcd(m,n) $ and $\gcd(mk_2 +nk_1,mn) $ are same.

I have already seen that Statement 2 implies Statement 1.

**Question**: does Statement 1 imply Statement 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Statement 1 does imply Statement 2. With

$$d = \gcd(m, n), \;\; m = de, \;\; n = df, \;\; \gcd(e, f) = 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

then

$$\gcd(mk_2 + nk_1, mn) = \gcd(dek_2 + dfk_1, d^2ef) = d\gcd(ek_2 + fk_1, def) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Let

$$j = \gcd(ek_2 + fk_1, def) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Statement 1 requiring $d$ to be a "proper divisor" means that $j \gt 1$ for *all* $k_1$ and $k_2$ where

$$\gcd(k_1, m) = \gcd(k_2, n) = 1 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Note that $e \mid def$ and $e \mid ek_2$, but $\gcd(e, fk_1) = 1$ since $\gcd(e, f) = 1$ from \eqref{eq1A}, plus $e \mid m$ and $\gcd(k_1, m) = 1$ from \eqref{eq4A} means $\gcd(e, k_1) = 1$. A similar argument applies for $f$. This means $\gcd(j, e) = \gcd(j, f) = 1$.

Thus, let $g$ be $d$ with all of the prime factors of $e$ or $f$ removed, i.e., $g$ is the largest factor of $d$ where $\gcd(e, g) = \gcd(f, g) = 1$. For Statement 1 to be true requires that, for all $k_1$ and $k_2$ which satisfy \eqref{eq4A}, we have $\gcd(ek_2 + fk_1, g) \gt 1$. Consider the prime factorization of $g$, i.e., for some $s \ge 1$ there are distinct primes $p_{i}$ and integers $r_{i} \ge 1$ for $1 \le i \le s$ such that

$$g = \prod_{i=1}^{s}p_{i}^{r_i} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

For each $p_{i}$, if $e \equiv f \pmod{p_i}$ then have

$$k_1 \equiv 1 \pmod{p_{i}}, \;\; k_2 \equiv 1 \pmod{p_{i}} \;\to\; k_{1}e + k_{2}f \equiv 2e \pmod{p_{i}} \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

else with $e \not\equiv f \pmod{p_i}$, then

$$k_1 \equiv 1 \pmod{p_{i}}, \;\; k_2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p_i} \;\to\; k_{1}e + k_{2}f \equiv e - f \pmod{p_{i}} \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Also, have

$$k_1 \equiv 1 \pmod{ef}, \;\; k_2 \equiv 1 \pmod{ef} \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

Let $h = (\prod_{i=1}^{s}q_i)ef$. Since all $p_i$ are relatively prime to each other and $ef$, the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) shows there are positive integers $k_1$ and $k_2$ which satisfy \eqref{eq6A} or \eqref{eq7A}, and \eqref{eq8A}, modulo $h$. Note also that $\gcd(k_1, h) = \gcd(k_2, h) = 1$. Since all prime factors of $m$ and $n$ divide $h$, this means \eqref{eq4A} holds.

If all of the $p_i$ are odd, using \eqref{eq3A}, we then get $\gcd(ek_2 + fk_1, g) = 1 \;\to\; j = 1$, so Statement 1 does *not* hold. However, if $p_i = 2$ for some $i$, then $d$ is even, so \eqref{eq1A} and \eqref{eq4A} show the only possible valid $k_1$ and $k_2$ are where both are odd. Since, as explained earlier, $2$ is not a factor of $e$ or $f$, they must also both be odd. Thus, $ek_2 + fk_1$ is the sum of $2$ odd terms, so it's even, which means that $2$ will then always divide $j$. Only under these conditions does Statement 1 hold, i.e., $d$ is always a proper divisor.

Since $d$ is even, with $e$ and $f$ both being odd, then \eqref{eq1A} means that the exponent of $2$ in $m$ and $n$ must both be the same positive value, i.e., Statement 2 then holds. This shows that Statement 1 implies Statement 2.

Comment: Thanks @john  it is a nice proof, there is a minor error that you have written mod p instead of $p_3$.

Comment: You only have $\forall k_1\,\forall k_2\,\exists p_3\,\dots$, not $\exists p_3\,\forall k_1\,\forall k_2\,\dots$.

Comment: You made cosmetic changes that didn’t address my concern at all. Your claim “statement 1 requires there to be a prime factor $p_3\mid d$, etc. for all $k_1$ and $k_2$ that satisfy (3)” is false, or at least, unjustified. Statement 1 only requires that for every $k_1$ and $k_2$ that satisfy (3), there is $p_3\mid d$ etc.; $p_3$ may be different each time, it depends on $k_1$ and $k_2$. There may not be a single $p_3$ that works for all. In particular, the subsequent argument where you try to rule out some $p_3$ by choosing specific $k_1$ and $k_2$ *depending on $p_3$* is invalid. The enemy ...

Comment: ... will only give you $p_3$ after you fix $k_1$ and $k_2$.

Comment: I believe Statements 1 and 2 are, indeed, equivalent, but you need to use the Chinese remainder theorem modulo all primes dividing $def$ to construct appropriate $k_1$ and $k_2$ such that $\gcd(ek_2+fk_1,def)=1$, making sure that (3) holds.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thank you for your additional explanation. I had misunderstood earlier, but I believe I have now fixed the solution. In particular, I now show that, if $d$ with all prime factors of $e$ and $f$ removed (what I label as $h$) is odd, then as you suggested, the Chinese remainder theorem can be used to show there are $k_1$ and $k_2$ such my $(3)$ is true and that $\gcd(ek_2 + fk_1, def) = 1$. Thus, $h$ must be even, so $d$ is even with $e$ and $f$ both being odd, with my previous conclusion that Statement 2 must be true then being appropriately applicable.

Comment: @Sky FYI, I had originally made a quite fundamental mistake, as Emil's comments above explain. However, I've updated my solution to, I believe, now work properly. I'm sorry for not noticing and correcting my mistake more promptly.

Comment: Good, I believe the new argument is correct.